# How to hide Visual Studio toolbars?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt-creator

I'm used to Qt Creator and want to learn more about Visual Studio. I would say Qt Creator is more clean while VS (by default) seems to show a bunch of tools on the toolbar.

Can we hide those toolbars and make VS look more like QtCreator?

I have VS 2019 installed on Windows though 2022 is the version I should be using these days, I guess.

Comment: Right-click it, turn off checkboxes.

Comment: ctrlQ lets you serach for any setting anywhere, type "toolbar' you will see 'customize>toolbar...', you can then choose tool bars

Comment: ***Can we hide those toolbars*** Yes, you can get rid of many of the toolbars in the customization.

Comment: The way in the answer works. You can right click on any toolbar to close it.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Does the answer below meet your needs? Also, you can  propose new features in the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/suggest).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this: 'View --> Toolbars --> uncheck all tools'

[image]